# nginx with nginx communication using http2 without ssl

Tags: nginx, http2

I've nginx-proxy and nginx-server docker containers.

`client browser < > nginx-proxy` is http2 and 443 via proxy_pass.

`nginx-proxy < > nginx-server` is http1 and I'd like to move it to http2 but without SSL - since they are both on same server, I don't see benefit of encrypting traffic.

I read nginx docs, and they say that it supports http2 without ssl. so I added `80 http2;` to listen directive in nginx-server vhost.

However, instead of showing website, browser downloads the file with following content:

```
0000 1204 0000 0000 0000 0300 0000 8000
0400 0000 0000 0500 ffff ff00 0004 0800
0000 0000 7fff 0000 0000 0807 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 01
```

it looks awfully like [this issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/741191/nginx-with-http2-enabled-downloads-everything?rq=1) but mine is not `browser <> nginx` issue but `nginx <> nginx` issue. Which shouldn't exist, because docs say nginx supports http2 without ssl.

How do I let nginx-proxy understand that backend nginx-server speaks http2... I guess that's the problem since hex dump says: `malformed packet`.

[This issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/765258/use-http-2-0-between-nginx-reverse-proxy-and-backend-webserver/765337#765337) states that it is not possible, and will not be implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your benefits of doing this will be minimal because the latency is very low between software on the same server. Given it's either very difficult or impossible I wouldn't spend your time on this.

Comment: it is also impossible as I found out.

Comment: Why is it impossible?  Most web browsers don't currently support HTTP/2 without SSL, but hopefully eventually some will, at least with third part plug-ins anyways. The speed of HTTP/2 without the overhead of SSL would be great to offer as an option.

Comment: For those that are trying to dispute this guy, directly from NGINX themselves....You are misinterpreting what HTTP2 means and its usefulness...In the OP scenario it would make it worse...

https://serverfault.com/questions/765258/use-http-2-0-between-nginx-reverse-proxy-and-backend-webserver

So to those that are down voting this answer or fighting against the answer of impossible, that is actually the correct answer. So all-in-all its just bringing a good question down.

Comment: It is noteworthy that while nginx reverse-proxy does not support HTTP2, haproxy does.